# .NET MVC - can i call script onSubmit at the same time as controller method

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, controller

I have view in my MVC project that looks like this:

```
@model MyModel
@{
    ViewBag.PageTitle = ..LocalizationResources.LogIn;
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h3>@ViewBag.PageTitle</h3>
</hgroup>

@using (Html.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", null, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", id = "simulatorForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ID, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ID)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            @Html.SubmitButton(..LocalizationResources.LogIn, null)
        </div>
    </div>

}

@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('simulatorForm').addEventListener('submit', handleFormSubmit);

        function handleFormSubmit() {
            console.log("form submitted");

            var form = document.getElementById('simulatorForm');

            var id = form.elements['ID'].value.trim();
            var name= form.elements['Name'].value.trim();

            if (id == "" || name == "") return;

            console.log("form validated");

            var user = {
                "id": id,
                "name": name 
            };

            .... my intern init code

            return false;
        }

    </script>
}
```

If i call it in console i don't see "form submitted" message logged. If i click submit without one field filled i see that message. Is it possible that on submit my script code doesn't execute and instead just go to controller method defined before form in html?

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing, where you don't see the "form submitted" message logged when the form is submitted, can occur if there are validation errors on the client-side or if there are issues with your JavaScript code.